# Python: EEL and SELENIUM / Cannot create installer

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller, eel

Could you please tell me how I can make a standalone `pyinstaller` app / what I should write in setup.py in oreder to make my app work with `pyinstaller`. Here is what my python script uses

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import pandas as pd
import random
import time
import math
import os, sys, subprocess
import eel
```

Note: my script uses an .xlsx file, a .txt file and since the GUI is built with `eel`, some .html, .css, .js files (located under ./web/...)

Here is how my setup.py looks like now:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['RaportariSmart.py']
DATA_FILES = ['Scoala.xlsx', './driver/chromedriver', './driver/chromedriver.exe', './web/ExportZilnic.txt', './web/index.html', './web/main.js', './web/style.css', './web/img/a3ca141c-event-arrows-bg.png', './web/css/bootstrap.min.css']
OPTIONS = {'includes':['selenium', 'eel', 'pandas', 'os', 'sys', 'subprocess']}

setup(
    name='Raporari Smart',
    version='1.0.0',
    author='Mihnea Manolache',
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

**Issue**: Whenever I pack the app with `pyinstaller`, it simply closes.

*P.S. I used the same script on a `tkinter` app and I managed to pack it successfully, but I cannot make it work with `eel`.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is really late, but if you are using **PyInstaller** try using **spec** file. Add your source of .exe file and destination of .exe file in **binaries** NOT in **datas**.

Here is a small snippet from the **spec** file.

```
a = Analysis(['app.py'],
         pathex=['D:\\tmp\\testProjects\\testEel'],
         binaries=[('venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\webdrivermanager\\87\\chromedriver.exe', '.')],
         datas=[('D:\\tmp\\testProjects\\testEel\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\eel\\eel.js', 'eel'), ('web', 'web')],
         hiddenimports=['bottle_websocket'],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
```

Run `PyInstaller app.py`

If the problem still persists probably you have given an incorrect path for `webdriver` in your program.

Also, I think it is better if you could download **webdrivers** on the machine automatically based on their browser version instead of providing a particular version with a .exe file.

There is this cool module that does download web drivers for the appropriate version, so you won't have to add web drivers to the .exe file [webdrivermanager](https://pypi.org/project/webdrivermanager/?fbclid=IwAR36z-qvBMFwtOvaglGVDTZK8niGiYdhlOU2dU3-LJZK-6PhKmgqEsuGwFQ). Change the download location of the web driver and point it to that path in the program.